# Start screen with bash command

Tags: unix, bash, gnu-screen

I need to start screen with some bash command to execute.  I'm trying:

```
screen -S test -d -m bash -c './test.php'
```

but have no result, screen didn't apear.

Even more, let's say I need to start something like this:

```
vlc -I ncurses --http-reconnect http://ip/ --sout '#duplicate{dst=std{access=http{user=,pwd=},mux=ts,dst=:51001}}' --ttl=255 --loop --repeat
```

How do I do this?  I'd like the screen to continue to display the results if the command completes.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting `screen` with `-d -m`. From the manpage:

> `-d -m`   Start  screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn’t attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

`screen -r` should attach your screen with the running command.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
screen -S test ./test.php
```

Comment: [screen is terminating]
that's all that i get

Comment: that means the script finished executing. do you want the screen to remain open after the script has finished executing?

Comment: sure, screen must be alive after script executed